# Using launchImage but keeping boundries in iphone5

Tags: ios5, ios6, retina-display, iphone-5

Is there anyway I could add a launch image using “Default-568@2x.png” but not run at 4" native resolution and keep boundaries.

I want to have a launch image, but want to keep everything else the same, and want to keep the black boundaries so that the background of the views does not stretch.

I am supporting ios5 so I can not use Autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not, because using the `Default-568@2x.png` means : I work in 4"...

Comment: How about if I add a Default@2x.png but not a Default-568@2x.png? Woudl that work?

Comment: Yes, without problem. If you don't want 4" compatibility simply remove the `Default-568@2x.png`, the `Default@2x.png` is just the retina version of the `Default.png`. This way your app will run in 3.5" mode on the 4" devices...